# Wordpress out of memory error in wp-db.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am doing a live update of a Wordpress site and after editing the front, i tried update it and it gave me this error:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 117440512) (tried to allocate 61440 bytes) in ../wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1851

I have done all memory increasing tweaks but nothing seems to work. All other functionality and pages work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one **WordPress Memory Exhausted Error**

You need to paste this code in **wp-config.php** file just before the line that says ‘That’s all, stop editing! Happy blogging.’

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

Comment: i have done that and increase it to 512M still get the error. i just deactivated all plugins and tried it again and am getting a different out memory error...Out of memory (allocated 117440512) (tried to allocate 167936 bytes) in ../wp-includes/functions.php on line 3721

Comment: Please check using phpinfo(); function after assign memory any updated.
Some times server provide limit of memory or contact to server provider for change phpini file.

Answer (score 2):

Your script is dying after a certain memory usage, You can get around it by increasing your `memory_limit` in php.ini file.

```
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: i have done this but still nothing is working as i said i have done all memory increasing tweaks but still same error..thanks

Comment: Have you find the solution for this issue?
I have same issue on wordpress site. I have added this *define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );* and also set memory_limit to 512M in php.ini file, but error still exist.